# How to get the selected option value from one component to other component in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have 2 components, I want to get the selected option value of login component to home component without storing it into localstorage, once you select the  option in login component, the selected option value should be display into home component . Here is the code below

### login.component.html

```
<select #mySelect (change)="onOptionsSelected(mySelect.value)">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
</select>
```

### login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  users:any;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  @Input() item: string;
  ngOnInit() {
 
  }
 
 onOptionsSelected(value:string){
     console.log("the selected value is " + value);
}
  
}
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getHeroes();
  }

}
```

### home.component.html

```
<div>home works</div>
```

Comment: Probably best if you follow the entire Tour of Heroes tutorial on angular.io first..

Answer (score 1):

Try using rxjs observable. You can create a service with behaviorsubject and emit the value whenever you call the option selected. In the home.component.ts file you have to subscribe to behaviorsubject declared in your service then it will notify your home component whenever there is a change. Try reading this link https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject